# Can I trust Boot Repair when it says "There was an error. You can now reboot"?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

My laptop used to have three operating systems on the same hard disk: Windows, Ubuntu 14, Ubuntu 18.  I tried removing Windows with [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) and got some error messages.  I tried recovering with [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), twice, and both times ended up with this message:

> An error occurred during the repair.
>
> You can now reboot your computer.
>   Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda1 file!

Should I really reboot my computer?  Or should I rather try to repair the error?

My intuition is to rather try to fix the error, but I don't know how to go about it.  The main error in the [log file that Boot-Repair produced](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VHVNv2Ws9V/) appears to be:

```
grub-install: error: /boot/efi doesn't look like an EFI partition.
grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot : exit code of grub-install :1
Error: no grub*.efi generated. Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com
```

This is the same error as discussed in [this thread](https://superuser.com/a/1053435/352692).  It is claimed there that the EFI system partition needs to be formated as `FAT` file system. GParted shows that, while my EFI system partition `/dev/sda1` indeed used to be formatted in FAT, after running OS-Uninstaller and Boot-Repair it is now formatted as `ext3` file system.  Could this be part of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EFI specification states that the EFI partition must be FAT. EXT3 will not work, your firmware cannot read that.
So if you can, convert the partition to FAT. After that reinstall GRUB or run Boot-repair again.

Comment: Do you have any idea why OS-Uninstaller or Boot-Repair might have reformatted the partition as ```ext3```?

Comment: Perhaps your UEFI is a bit buggy, this happens a lot with OEM systems, who try to implement their own ideas. This can be why Boot-repair also mentions to set your BIOS to boot from SDA

Comment: After reformatting the EFI partition as ```FAT32``` Boot-Repair indeed ran without errors. (Will accept this answer in case I can actually boot …)